# JQuery 1.9 - Click Not Firing w/ Wijmo

Tags: jquery, wijmo

For the life of me, can't figure out why this won't work.  Fiddle said it would, even with 2 different method.  I tried in both area, Ready and Function. It worked prior to upgrading from JQuery 1.8.3, now it won't work in JQuery 1.9.1.

The head contains:

> ```
> jquery-1.9.1.js
> jquery-ui.js  (1.9.2)
> jquery.wijmo-open.all.3.20131.7.js
> jquery.wijmo-pro.all.3.20131.7.js
> ```

```
$('div[name^="AlSt_"]').click(function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('name').split("_");
    alert(data[1]);
});

$('div[name^="AlSt_"]').on('click',function(){
    var data = $(this).attr('name').split("_");
    alert(data[1]);
});

<div name="AlSt_02"><span>02_693</span></div>
```

It should give me result of "02", but the click/on('click') is not firing on my website.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: you have `<div>` inside `<span>` ???? :)..this is invalid

Comment: so it should be "opposite" then?  I dunno why it worked for me prior to 1.9 :)

Comment: yes try it with "opposite" `<span>` inside `<div>`

Comment: I changed to <div><span></span></div>, still same result, not firing :(

Comment: and make sure you change the selector `span` to `div` too  :)

Comment: Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @barmar - right now its in $(function(){}), will try with dom.ready

Comment: @barmar - just tried inside dom.ready, no go :(

Comment: dom ready and $(function(){}); are the same thing

Comment: do you see any errors?

Comment: No error whatsoever, nothing in Console Log either.  I'm using chrome, i checked on Firefox (Firebug as well) and no error either.

Comment: Perhaps try out the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) and see what the console says.

Comment: Ok did that and give me "warning" but not error:

JQMIGRATE:
jQuery.attrFn is deprecated jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:40
console.trace() jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42
migrateWarn jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:42
Object.defineProperty.get jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:57
supportTouch jquery.wijmo-open.all.3.20131.7.js:1982
jQuery.extend.each jquery-1.9.1.js:648
wijmo.touch.wijmo.touch jquery.wijmo-open.all.3.20131.7.js:1978
wijmo jquery.wijmo-open.all.3.20131.7.js:2336
(anonymous function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution after spending hours and hours searching, dunno if it's "proper" idea tho, according to JQuery site:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-event-not-firing-timing-issue

```
  $(document).on('click','div[name^="AlSt_"]',function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('name').split("_");
        alert(data[1]);
  });
```

So far, tested it and it works.  Odd method for sure, but it works :)